# How do I run the local version of gulp and the local version of any node executables? ie, not the globally installed versions

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to set up a build environment for react using gulp.

I installed babel 7 into my project directory using the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-babel@7 babel-core babel-preset-env
```

However, when I run gulp I get the error:

> "Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are
>   sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core,"

If I do 'which gulp' I get back '/home/bob/.nvm/...gulp'.

How do I run the local version of both gulp and any executables in my local project?

Answer (score 1):

`npx` can be used to run packages local to projects.

```
$ npm i --save-dev gulp
$ npx gulp -v
```

For Gulp specifically, there's a `gulp-cli` package that will run the local Gulp package when you run `gulp`:

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-cli
$ gulp -v
```